# Webpack gives me "Module has no exported member..." errors for files in node_modules even when no module is required

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I have a problem with Webpack. It compiles and tree-shakes correctly, but gives me hundreds of errors, because it for some reason does something with type definitions in node_modules, even though it shouldn't, because no module is required/imported in my entry point.

My webpack.config.js:

```
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require("awesome-typescript-loader").ForkCheckerPlugin;
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry:
    {
        browser: __dirname + "/source/index.tsx"
    },

    module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            { test: /(\.ts|\.tsx)$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: "css-loader?modules" }) },
            { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader" },
            { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "url-loader" },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
        ]
    },

    plugins:
    [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env": { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production") } }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compressor: { warnings: false } }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: "vendor", minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource) }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("browser.css"),
    ],

    output:
    {
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].js",
        path:  __dirname + "/build/browser/"
    }
};
```

My entrypoint (source/index.tsx) - basically nothing:

```
console.log("Test");
```

Errors it gives me (shortened, they're all similar):

```
ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\match.d.ts:12:15
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'History'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\match.d.ts:16:80
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'Location'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\useRouterHistory.d.ts:1:9
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'History'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\useRouterHistory.d.ts:1:18
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'HistoryOptions'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\useRouterHistory.d.ts:1:34
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'HistoryQueries'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\useRouterHistory.d.ts:1:50
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'CreateHistory'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\useRoutes.d.ts:4:47
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'CreateHistory'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\Tom\VSCodeProjects\personal\webpack-test\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\useRoutes.d.ts:4:68
Module '"C:/Users/Tom/VSCodeProjects/personal/webpack-test/node_modules/history/lib/index"' has no exported member 'CreateHistory'.
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding `"exclude": [ "node_modules" ]` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly that does not work, nothing has changed.

Comment: Hm, maybe try setting `exclude: ['node_modules']` in `module.loaders`?

Comment: I tried these:
- `{ test: /(\.ts|\.tsx)$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader", exclude: ['node_modules'] }`
- `{ test: /(\.ts|\.tsx)$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader", options: { exclude: ['node_modules'] } }`
- `/node_modules/` and `[ /node_modules/ ]` instead of `'node_modules'`

But nothing works. :/

Comment: Did you try to set both? This is my current configuration.

Comment: Maybe an issue on their Github helps? There is already a thread: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/209

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation is to examine each of your webpack loaders and make sure they are not somehow causing this to happen. I had a similar issue, and I was able to resolve it by using a different CSS loader (sass) than I was using before.